# How to set or disable the Query Timeout with a C++'s CDatabase ODBC connection to a SQL Server database

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, query-timeout

I need to have a query run by some code. Running the query in MSSMS takes a minute and a half (not too shabby for over 4M rows).
In code I open the connection with

```
CDatabase *base = new CDatabase () ;
base->OpenEx ("Driver={SQL Server};Server=Computer\\User;Database=base;") ;
```

I can then create `CRecordset` objects and run queries. The `SELECT COUNT` query works properly (gives ~4M). The first `SELECT cols` query (fetching some attributes) works properly. Their respective `CRecordset` are properly closed and cleaned. The second `SELECT cols` query (big join that returns the 4M rows) times out on every try.

I do not know how to set up the query timeout value, how that parameter would be called, or where to set it in the first place. I tried [many combinations](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/) of parameters in the connection string, I tried editing the ODBC pilot pooling options. I am not interested in using another ODBC connection object, but I can set up a DSN and connect through it instead of using the direct connection string.

Worst comes to worst I'll just paginate it all but right now it's a hassle, and since the query can timeout, logically there should be a way to set that timeout too, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Query timeout is not a connection string parameter. You're probably looking for the [CDatabase::SetQueryTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdatabase-class#setquerytimeout) member function.

Comment: Huh. Oracle's `QTO` connection string parameter got me believing that would be the case. I'll try that method tomorrow, can you put it in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query timeout is not a connection string parameter, at least not for SQL Server. You're probably looking for the [CDatabase::SetQueryTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdatabase-class#setquerytimeout) member function.